# Java: Latest version of file (modified during execution of program) not being used

Tags: java, file, version

I'm writing a program that imports a file aClass.java from a server, saves it in my project, compiles it then uses it afterwards. But sometimes the file on the server is modified, and when this is done my program modifies the file I have in my project too, and here's the issue: If there's a modification made on the file on the server, when I run my program the first time all it does it update my file, but it still uses the old version of it, it's not until I run it a second time that it uses the newer version.

I thought of a couple of solutions to solve this problem, here they are:

- Try forcing the restart of my program programmatically, this way when I run it the first time, in the middle of the process it restarts and hence takes into account the latest version -> I wasn't able to find how to do this
- Initialise an object of the same class once the update is done, the calling my main method from it -> Here my code uses the old version again, so this doesn't solve the problem
- I tried using addShutdownHook in which I tried doing the same as above: Initialize another object of the same class then calling the main method through it -> I get the folloing exception "Exception in thread "AWT-Windows" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress"
- I created another class that is a copy of my class I'm using, then I try calling it after I update the file, I get the same results as above

Does anyone have a solution for this issue ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you will have to dynamically load the "new" version dynamically after you modify it. Once java has loaded a class it will not load one with the same qualified name again

Comment: Okay I see. And how can I load a class dynamically ?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html check this out. You'll need to use a Classloader to do it

Comment: Another side effect of dynamic class loading is that objects using the old class are not the same as objects of the new class; even if they have the same fully qualified class name. Because the dynamic classes will have different instance of the class loader they are effectively different class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found [this link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html#example) to be very helpful. I used the example given in it to reload classes in my code